# Tokenizer for C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any functionality built into the .NET framework somewhere to tokenize C# code? I'm not looking to build a tokenizer in C#, I'm looking for something that can tokenize C# source code.

Comment: What did you end up using? Did any of these answers help?

Answer (score 3):

The only thing that comes to mind is a parser generator like [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), which has [C# Sample Grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1134052630849/csharp_v1.zip) available. Bison/Flex also looks like it has pretty decent [C# grammar](http://www.cs.nuim.ie/~jpower/Research/csharp/Index.html) as well. Parsing any language and then actually making sense of it is fairly difficult, so I wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

No, not built into the framework.

However, you may want to look at [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/), and [C# Parser](http://csparser.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex, as they both provide a parser/lexer for at least simple C#

Answer (score 0):

The GOLD Parser too has a [C# grammar](http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/grammars/index.htm) (to parse C#), and [run-time engines written in C#](http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/engine/c-sharp/index.htm) (so that you can execute that grammar using C# code).